# read an xml file into database

Tags: php, mysql, xml

I want to store the contents of an xml file in the database. Is there an easy way to do it?
Can i write some script that can do the task for me?

The schema of the XML file looks like this:

```
<schedule start="20100727120000 +0530" stop="20100727160000 +0530" ch_id="0210.CHNAME.in">
    <title>Title_info</title>
    <date>20100727</date>
    <category>cat_02</category>
  </schedule>
```

One thing to note is:
How do I read the start time? I need the time +0530 added to the time?

Thank you so much.

Comment: Try using a RegEx to parse it.

Comment: Too bad MySQL 5.5 isn't released to public, so you could use [LOAD XML](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/load-xml.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

look up `simple_xml` on the php page - off hand I'm not too hot on it, but basically you will end up with a loop which will add your data to an object eg:

`$xml`

and you will be able to call tags as such `$xml->schedule->title` `$xml->schedule->date` and `$xml->schedule->category` and you will be able to call attributes as such `$xml->schedule[start]` but you might wanna check that.

I had to do this recently for a client, and this was the best way I could find. The attributes may be tricky - I can't quite remember but you might have to look into namespaces and such... anyway, find simple_xml and you're on the right tracks.

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably want to create a table called `schedules` that matches your data, then read the contents of the XML file with an XML parser of your choice. [SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) might be the right tool for this job.

As for the dates, I recommend you try using the function [date_parse_from_format()](http://fi.php.net/manual/en/function.date-parse-from-format.php).